# Magento 2.3 : Getting qty from all assigned sources (Multi warehouse inventory) programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, qty, multi-source-inventory

How to get qty from all assigned sources (Multi warehouse inventory) programmatically i.e sources and corresponding quantities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$sourceItemsBySku = $this->getSourceItemsBySku->execute($product->getSku());
$config['stockData'][$productId] = [];

foreach ($sourceItemsBySku as $sourceItem) {
    $source = $sourceItem->getSourceCode();
    $quantity = $sourceItem->getQuantity();

    $config['stockData'][$productId][$source] = $quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Source Item management APIs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/manage-source-items.html

For example, to retrieve all Quantities among all Sources where SKU = new_product2 located

you can do with next REST request:

`GET /V1/inventory/source-items?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=new_product2&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

Or in the code you can just call next service:
namespace Magento\InventoryApi\Api;

```
/**
 * Sugar service for find SourceItems by SKU
 *
 * @api
 */
interface GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface[]
     */
    public function execute(string $sku): array;
}
```

https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventoryApi/Api/GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface.php